# Как обновить state по завершению нескольких сетевых запросов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Как правильно обновить `state` за 1 раз после выполнения всех сетевых запросов?

```
// idList === ["34563", "123423", "2359239"]

const [itemsList, setItemsList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const updatedItemsList = [];

  idList.forEach((id) => {
    const item = doSomeFetch(id);
    updatedItemsList.push(item)
  })

  setItemsList(updatedItemsList)
}, [props.idList])
```

Ожидаемый результат:

- проходимся по массиву с `id`
- делаем запрос к серверу на каждый `id`
- получаем объект по его `id` и добавляем в массив
- по завершению всех запросов полученный массив прокидываем в стейт

Comment: `Promise.all` что бы послать все запросы параллельно и обработать результат всех запросов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
useEffect(() => {

  Promise.all(idList.map((id) => doSomeFetch(id)))
    .then((updatedItemsList) => setItemsList(updatedItemsList))
    .catch(console.error)

}, [props.idList])
```

<sup>можно даже немного короче</sup>

```js
useEffect(() => {

  Promise.all(idList.map(doSomeFetch))
    .then(setItemsList).catch(console.error)

}, [props.idList])
```

Comment: А какой смысл здесь использовать  сниппеты кода, они же не будут работать?

Comment: @0xdb в этой штуке проще написать код не открывая ide. вот, весь смысл - [ide](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1281554/2659) и [не ide](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1281444/2659)